# view Crystal report

Tags: asp.net

SELECT T.GLTR_COMP_CODE, 
       T.GLTR_ACCT_CODE,
       T.GLTR_DEPT_NO,
       M.GLMA_ACCT_NAME , 
       CAST(T.GLTR_PSTNG_TYPE AS VARCHAR) + CAST(T.GLTR_PSTNG_NO AS VARCHAR) REF_NO, 
       CAST(T.GLTR_DOC_CODE AS VARCHAR) + CAST(T.GLTR_OUR_DOC_NO AS VARCHAR) DOC_NO,
       T.GLTR_DOC_DATETIME DOC_DATE,
       T.GLTR_DOC_NARR NARRATIVE,
       T.GLTR_PSTNG_DATETIME,
       CASE SIGN(T.GLTR_TRAN_AMT) WHEN + 1 THEN T.GLTR_TRAN_AMT ELSE 0 END DEBIT,
       CASE SIGN(T.GLTR_TRAN_AMT) WHEN - 1 THEN T.GLTR_TRAN_AMT ELSE 0 END CREDIT,
       T.GLTR_TRAN_AMT AMOUNT,
       T.GLTR_FC_CODE FC_CODE,
       T.GLTR_FC_AMT FC_AMOUNT
       FROM GLAS_GL_TRANSACTIONS T
       LEFT OUTER JOIN GLAS_GL_MASTERS M ON M.GLMA_COMP_CODE = T.GLTR_COMP_CODE
       AND M.GLMA_ACCT_CODE = T.GLTR_ACCT_CODE
       AND M.GLMA_DEPT_NO = T.GLTR_DEPT_NO 
       WHERE T.GLTR_PSTNG_DATETIME BETWEEN COALESCE(@DATE_FROM, T.GLTR_PSTNG_DATETIME)
       AND COALESCE(@DATE_TO, T.GLTR_PSTNG_DATETIME)
       AND T.GLTR_COMP_CODE =@COMP_CODE
       AND M.GLMA_YEAR = CONVERT(NUMERIC(8, 2), DATEPART(YYYY, @DATE_FROM))
       AND M.GLMA_ACCT_CODE BETWEEN COALESCE(@ACCT_CODE_FROM, M.GLMA_ACCT_CODE)
       AND COALESCE(@ACCT_CODE_TO, M.GLMA_ACCT_CODE)
       ORDER BY T.GLTR_ACCT_CODE, T.GLTR_PSTNG_DATETIME, T.GLTR_DOC_CODE, T.GLTR_OUR_DOC_NO

This is my query in dataset...how can i view this in crystal report ......some of fields above have concatenate how can i display?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have created the dataset in your report you should be able to add the field to the report and view it.

The one thing I notice is that you do not have alias on your concatenated fields which may cause problems when designing your report.